# How to create a Java String object in a Python script after using JCC to create an interface to a Java Library?

Tags: java, python, string, interface, jcc

I have a Java library which I have created a CPython interface using JCC from Apache. When I do the following, the "String" object appears, so I suppose there is a suitable interface to the String object ("p" is the library I load using "import library as p").

```
dir(p)
... 
'OutputStream', 'Package', 'PrintStream', 'PrintWriter', 'RuntimeException',
'SecurityException', 'Serializable', 'Short', 'StackTraceElement', 'String', 
...
```

What is the way to create a Java String from Python using this library I have "interfaced"?. There is no answer around on the internet and the JCC documentation is too short.

I don't want a Python string, but a Java String I can pass to an interfaced Java method.